# Java resultset errors when encountering a null

Tags: java, sql, multidimensional-array, resultset

I have some code that is putting the resultset from a query into a 2 dimensional array.  However when the array encounters a null from the resultset, it errors.  How do I fix this?

```
  query = "SELECT * FROM E_CMS WHERE BOXADDR_AREA IS NULL ORDER BY CBOXID ASC ";
  rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    //insert the table into the 2 dimensional array
    while (rs.next()) {
    e_cms_Array[count][0] = rs.getString("CBOXID");
    e_cms_Array[count][1] = rs.getString("CBOXADD").replace("'","");
    e_cms_Array[count][2] = rs.getString("MFLPU");
    e_cms_Array[count][3] = rs.getString("SATLPU");
    e_cms_Array[count][4] = rs.getString("BOXTYPE");
    e_cms_Array[count][5] = rs.getString("SVCCLASS");
    e_cms_Array[count][6] = rs.getString("LOCATION_TYPE").replace("'","");
    e_cms_Array[count][7] = rs.getString("CHANGE_DATE");
    e_cms_Array[count][8] = rs.getString("DEL_FLAG");
    e_cms_Array[count][9] = rs.getString("DECAL_PRINT_DT");
    e_cms_Array[count][10] = rs.getString("BOXADDR_AREA").replace("'","");
    e_cms_Array[count][11] = rs.getString("LASTMF_AREA_O");
    e_cms_Array[count][12] = rs.getString("LASTSAT_AREA_O");

    System.out.println(count + " :: " + 
      e_cms_Array[count][0]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][1]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][2]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][3]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][4]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][5]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][6]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][7]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][8]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][9]+"|"+
       e_cms_Array[count][10]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][11]+"|"+
      e_cms_Array[count][12]);

    count++;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message and stack trace?

Comment: @JB Nizet `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at forecast_transmission.get_e_cms(forecast_transmission.java:106)
 at forecast_transmission.main(forecast_transmission.java:44)`

Comment: Please provide the complete code or an SSCCE. It's impossible that adding a null value to an array causes an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason for the error, except for you doing things like

```
  e_cms_Array[count][1] = rs.getString("CBOXADD").replace("'","");
```

Just replace it by

```
  String s = rs.getString("CBOXADD");
  e_cms_Array[count][1] = s==null ? s : s.replace("'","");
```

or better write a null-tolerant method for this replacement.

Comment: ah, of course, sometimes it takes another set of eyes to notice something right in front of your face, thank you

Comment: If this fixed the problem, you should check it and vote it up :)

Comment: My easiest-earned reputation ever. :)